# Non-integer primary key exception

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hello guys i m working with a school assignment which has a simple form and database.

there is students table in database.

Problem:

This program works when i Enter stu_ID as integer which is primary key like 1234,
problem arise when i enter stu_ID as non-integer.(assignment requirement).
Like BSCS-122.it gives following exception

```
'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' {"Invalid column name 'BSCS'."}
```

I m working with Visual studio 2015 
SQL Server 2008 R2 express.

```
students
    stu_Id       varchar(50) PK
    stu_Name     varchar(50)
    Stu_Age      int
    stu_Semester int
    stu_City     varchar(50)

+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
| stu_Id     | stu_Name        | Stu_Age | stu_Semester | stu_City    | 
+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
| BSCS-122   | Danish Kareem   | 22      |      5       | Decya       |
| MBA-233    | Kamran          | 23      |      5       | JPT         |
| .. ....    | ............... | ..... ..| ....... .....| ...... .....|
+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

The c# code is bellow.

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-VESS66M\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Persons;Integrated Security=True");
        try
        {
            //
            objSqlConnection.Open();
            string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO students VALUES (" +stu_ID.Text+ ",'" + stu_Name.Text + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(stu_Age.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(stu_Semester.Text) + "','" + stu_City.Text + "')";
            SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, objSqlConnection);
            objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //
            this.studentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.personsDataSet.students);
            //
            MessageBox.Show("Student " + txtName.Text + " had been added Successfully", "Added Succefull", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            objSqlConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use parameterized SQL queries. Your problem is that you're not opening the id string with a `'` in your query. Fi you use sql parameters you'll fix this problem and avoid sql injection issues.

Comment: Have you learned about SQL injection yet? If you use parameters in your query then you can avoid the headache of missing quotes around strings (which is the issue here). Numbers don't need quotes, but input such as BSBC does. http://bobby-tables.com/csharp

Comment: when you build the SQL - it's ok to have an integer free of quotes, but text has to be inside quotes - you are building the stu_ID part without single quotes - seems to be the immediate problem

Comment: In addition to the above comments about enclosing strings in quotes - as an explanation of what is happening - because it is not in quotes BSCS-122 is being treated as an expression - current contents of column BSCS minus 122.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and quick fix is to add single quotes arount `stu_ID`  but that's prone to SQL injection: "'"+stu_ID.Text+"'"

Better way is to add parameters to your query, to prevent SQL injection:

```
string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO students VALUES (@stuID, @stuName, @stuAge, @stuSemester, @stuCity)";
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("stuId", stu_ID.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("stuName", stu_Name.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("stuAge", Convert.ToInt32(stu_Age.Text)));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("stuSemester", Convert.ToInt32(stu_Semester.Text)));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("stuCity", stu_City.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text field value needs to be surrounded by single quotes like:

`"INSERT INTO students VALUES ('" + stu_ID.Text + "')"`

However, this is still an extremely bad idea as you're leaving yourself open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  If you aren't going to use a framework (such as Entity Framework) for your data layer, you at least need to use an [SQLParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) to inject your values.